# What is the origin and purpose of AUTHORS.md?

Tags: markdown, human-readable

While **Humans.txt** has a very well set up and informative [website](http://humanstxt.org) explaining its purposes, highlighting its uses and even showcasing some of them, I can not find any similar details on **AUTHORS.md**.

I spotted a [tweet](https://twitter.com/ekrubnivek/status/366598629164720128) pointing to a GitHub repo, "Hulk" and specifically one feature of it - [generating an AUTHORS.md](https://github.com/kevinburke/hulk/blob/master/Makefile#L7). This was the source of my curiosity, so I asked the author about it. Not even he was sure about [its exact purpose vs. that of *humans.txt*](https://twitter.com/ekrubnivek/status/366988644579414016).

A [search on Google](https://encrypted.google.com/search?num=20&hl=en&biw=1680&bih=933&q=AUTHORS.md+vs+humans.txt&oq=AUTHORS.md+vs+humans.txt&gs_l=serp.3...15527.16195.0.17863.4.4.0.0.0.0.314.778.1j1j1j1.4.0....0...1c.1.24.serp..4.0.0.R-ubYByjhVA) yielded only one developer related result, a GitHub repo named [ZakharovviHumansTxtBundle](https://github.com/zakharovvi/ZakharovviHumansTxtBundle). All the other results were related to medical issues.
Similarly, searching for "authors.md" on both [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=authors+md) and [StackExchange](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=authors+md) yielded **no** results. Not one. Conversely, the query ["humans.txt"](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=humans.txt) yields many.

Comment: Note: I would have created the tags [[humans.txt]] and [[authors.md]] but lack enough rep to do so.

Comment: Note that you probably shouldn't create a tag if there's only one question about it.

Comment: Thanks. Weird, though. What's the reason for not doing so (apart from abuse-potential)

Comment: Tags are there to quickly see what questions are about and to search across a specific topic. A unique tag is too specific for both of those. Searching for it [normally](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=AUTHORS.md) gets you directly here, so [searching by tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/authors.md) would have little purpose. And the fact that you can't find details on it indicates that most people probably don't know what it is, but if they do, they'll find it in the question title. And people often only use one tag, making the question that much less visible if that were it.

Comment: Makes sense. As long as the search algorithms are powerful and intelligent - which I'm sure they are on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

Origin... no idea.

The purpose of an AUTHORS file is, typically, to identify individuals who have made substantial contributions to a project. This seems to be done in a variety of ways. Such files may identify project founder(s), identify a current "development team" (individuals currently engaged in the project), identify those have made "significant" contributions to the project in the past, etc.

A second purpose, for some, is to, through acknowledgement of contributions, motivate others to consider contributing to the project (e.g., see the "encouragement" at
[opensource.guide](https://opensource.guide/building-community/#share-ownership-of-your-project) in this regard).

Explicit assertion of authorship typically confers legal rights such as copyright. Google has clearly thought about this a bit (e.g., see [Google's open source contributions guidelines](https://opensource.google.com/docs/releasing/authors/) and [additional elaboration on the guidelines](https://opensource.google.com/docs/releasing/contributions/)).

With the widespread use of version control systems, the identity of the individuals responsible for various components of the source code in most projects is pretty clearly established at a pretty granular level via the VCS metadata. Thus, there is now likely less perceived need to add author name(s) to the headers of individual source files. This might tie in with the second purpose noted above: e.g., (a) perception of "sole ownership" might discourage collaboration and (b) an AUTHORS file establishes a way to clearly give credit if putting authorship information in header files is discouraged for a given project.

Answer (score 1):

The earliest use I've seen, and the reason I use it for my projects, is in the recommendations for new GNU projects:

http://inti.sourceforge.net/tutorial/libinti/autotoolsproject.html

> There are a few files that the GNU standard says must be present in the top-level directory, and if not found Automake will report an error.  Enter the following command to create these files:
>
> `$ touch AUTHORS NEWS README ChangeLog`

I remember seeing this file in GNU software back in the late 90s.

The `.md` extension is just to have GitHub parse it as markdown.